# Pass a condition in a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

In my project, I need to write a sql query but I have an issue.
For example, I have a thousand institutions and I need to test several fields for those institutions, but sometimes some fields don't exist for an institution so my query discard this institution in the result.
So what I want to do, is to test if yes or not the field exist for this institution and do the condition test if yes or pass the condition if not.

Is there a way to do it simply in the 'WHERE' part like something like this :

```
where if(e.field1 exist) then e.field1='plop1' and if(e.field2 exist) then e.field2='plop2'
```

Comment: By "doesn't exist" do you mean the column value is null?

Comment: This is not a real question in this format. please add the relevant tables and queries to the question. use paragraphs. BTW, the database doesn't seem to be normalized.

Comment: Yes it is, tables are irrelevant, he is asking more for a concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the coalesce function for this purpose:

```
SELECT COALESCE(e.field1, 'plop1') AS field1 FROM table e
```

This will replace NULL values for the field with the String 'plop1', yielding a not-null result for each record.

See also http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php

EDIT: I'm assuming the field "field1" exists in your database schema. Otherwise, this is an entirely different problem that might have be tackled at the database / application design level.

Answer (score 2):

```
where (e.field1 is null or e.field1 = 'plop1')
    and (e.field2 is null or e.field2 = 'plop2')
```

Comment: assuming that your definition of 'exist' is 'not null'

Comment: I don't think by "doesn't exist" he meant the null value.

Comment: What else? Once a row is a table it can't "opt out" of a few columns.

Comment: I don't know... the question is too confusing.

Comment: The most likely scenario is that business-wise the "Institution" entity can have some optional fields ("some fields don't exist for an institution") and most commonly one will use a NULL value for that column in a DB representation of that entity.

Comment: The "don't exist" part was a little bit confusing, actually. What I meant is there is no entry for the field so we can't test with the null value.

Comment: Well, in this case what value does the column contain?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I solved my problem. I put the condition of the left join right after and not in a where clause i.e. [code] LEFT JOIN MYTABLE ON a.id = b.id AND field1 = plop1[/code] and not [code]LEFT JOIN MYTABLE ON a.id = b.id WHERE field1 = plop1[/code]

Answer (score -1):

you have to use REF CURSOR

like below

```
TYPE curvar_type IS REF CURSOR;
   curvar    curvar_type;

    my_query_v   VARCHAR2(1000) := 'select * from something';
    where_v       VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
       ...
       IF (abc is null)
           where_v := 'xyz=null';
       ELSE
           where_v := 'xyz='''||abc'' ';
       END IF;

        my_query_v := my_query_v || ' WHERE ' || where_v;
       ...
```